# Just getting my masters in cyber security but still looking for a job

Tags: penetration-test

I completed the masters degree program from Perdue online last April '18. I see there is a great need in this field. I have been looking for a job daily but still haven't been able to find anything. Everyone asks for a year of experience but not willing to give me that foot in the door, and I have only had one interview after all of my resume sending and application filling.

Is there anything I should be doing different, or any companies in particular which allow recent graduates a chance?

I do have experience in the technology field. I was a dba while in college for the bioinformatics lab and also worked on the website. I contracted as a pc specialist, and currently do consulting for companies. While I was in school I also performed a penetration test of a tax business and mitigated all their vulnerabilities and created a security policy and did training for the employees.

If anyone has any pointers or would like to see my resume please respond.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the sort of question we answer here. You need to be doing *informational interviews* in your area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing the right thing in asking. Be prepared for honest feedback.

I volunteer and run a mentoring program to answer exactly this question, and I'm helping people with BS and below get 65K/year jobs with little or no experience. Here's what advice I can offer:

Reconsider your resume. If you have only received one interview, there's a good chance your resume is not well suited to what you're looking for, the template doesn't look polished and professional, or it's missing key features. It needs to include ALL aspects of "experience," including open source contributions, playing with labs at home (yes, it's "experience"), etc. Consider having a security professional you're friends with look at it (or an online resume service if not - or, if all else fails, I'll look at it myself just to help because I enjoy helping people go places... tag me in a comment and I'll find a way to make contact with you). Ask them what you're doing wrong an

Consider the jobs you are applying for. I'm seeing help desk and desktop support jobs pop up everywhere. I'm a Community College Cyber Security teacher and I can't get enough students to fill all the jobs I'm seeing for Jr. network engineers, sysadmins, help desk, etc. You may want to be in security, but what you need to understand is that "entry level security" is *actually* 1-3 years of regular IT experience, *not* fresh out of college. I have a Masters, years of security and IT experience, a dozen certs and a SANS community mentor. I don't mean this to be condescending, but if we are both applying for the same job, there are probably 3-4 people like me who have certs and experience who will get called before you. Consider looking at different jobs.

Network, network, network! WHO you know is crucial. Take a few recruiters out to lunch and ask them for direct feedback.

Find a mentor who has the job you want. Take him out to lunch once a month (if he's any kind of good person, they'll offer to pay, but you should first because you're receiving something of intense value) and ask how he/she got where they are, and what they would have done differently to get there faster.

Learn soft skills. Taking the Myers-Briggs Type indicator ([16personalities.com](https://16personalities.com) is a good place to start). This can tell you what others see about you that you could be missing. I strongly encourage you to learn about EQ. "EQ 2.0" is a phenomenal place to start. You could be a terrific hacker/programmer/whatever but if you have a low EQ, no one cares because you're difficult to work with. (I'm not saying this is the case, just offering a possibility).

Get some certs. Certs prove that you have both the textbook knowledge AND the hands-on skill.

You're asking the right questions. Sometimes criticism hurts, but it provides a long-term value of producing what you're looking for - IF you can accept it.

Good luck. The security and IT sectors are absolutely booming, and I'm consistently helping people get good paying jobs with little or no experience. You can, too!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I appreciate your words. I have an updated resume and I make it job specific for each position I am applying too. I have a background in IT but not sure if it's strong enough. I do agree that my resume may need to be looked over. Let me know how I can get in contact with you and I can send my most recent one to you. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree, I've been in a similar position. Currently a software engineer (at a cybersecurity company), doing an infosec masters and working my ass off learning various bits and bobs. Yet when it comes to getting a job more directly related to infosec, you *need* that experience.... Another thing they would probably consider worthy would be certifications - my feeling is that for some reason a degree doesn't cut it in terms of experience.

Or to be respected at a company that has such roles and rely on that leverage when applying to a more security-related role.

I think most people in the industry don't really want to trust people to grow into a role like this. They want seasoned professionals. I'd be glad to be convinced otherwise

Comment: This is more of a comment than an "answer." Just an FYI for future reference as a new contributor.

Comment: Thank you, I know this isn't the kind of "question"/"answer" suited for stack exchange, but it resonated with me and I know from experience that alienation feels pretty bad :)

Comment: I know xenocratus I am trying to remain positive and motivated to getting a position in Cyber. Trying all my avenues.